# Radio Button not storing the value in database?

Tags: php, database, radio-button

I got a problem this is simple form i have to submit the data through radio buttons problem is that no value is displayed in database neither of disases name nor for yes,no option I have created database with name doctor with fields id ,dis_name,and ans.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require 'db.php';
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // keep track validation errors
    $disError = null;
    $ansError = null;

    // keep track post values
    $dis_name = isset($_POST['dis_name']);
    $ans=isset($_POST['ans']);

    // validate input
    $valid = true;
    if (empty($dis_name)) {
        $disError = 'Please enter Diseases Name';
        $valid = false;
    }
    if (empty($ans)) {
        $ansError = 'Please check one of option';
        $valid = false;
    }

    // insert data

    if ($valid) {
        if(isset($_POST['dis_name'])){
            $pdo = Database::connect();

            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO diseases (dis_name) values(?)";

            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($dis_name));
            Database::disconnect();
            //header("location: diseases.php");
        }
    }
}
?>

//some html code here

<div class="control-group <?php echo   !empty($ansError)?'error':'';?>">
    <label class="check">Have you suffered pain preiviously???</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" <?php if (isset($ans) && $ans=="yes") echo "checked";?>
    value="Yes">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="choice"<?php if (isset($ans) && $ans=="no") echo "checked";?>
    value="No">No
<?php                   
//if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['choice'])){
        $ans=isset($_POST['ans']);
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO diseases (question) values(?)";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(isset($_POST['choice'])));
        Database::disconnect();
    }
//}
?>

`isset() it gives undefined index warning.`
```

Comment: It should be 
<input type="radio" name="choice[]" value="Yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="choice[]" value="No">No

Comment: ^ You need to specify a value for each input, that will be passed through to the `$_POST` superglobal.

Comment: is it necessary to put name type as array i.e choice[] because when i am setting it as choice[] non of the value is inserted in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `ans` stands for *answer* which is filled by the `radio` control value. And this is how you fetch it on server side:

```
$ans=isset($_POST['ans']);
```

In your html it is actually `choice`

Shouldn't you be getting it like this?

```
$ans=isset($_POST['choice']);
```

EDIT:

And why would you use `isset` function to fetch post value?

Comment: it gives undefined index warning.

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` returns boolean and the input is named 'choice'.
Perhaps you mean:

```
if( isset($_POST['choice']) ){
    $ans = $_POST['choice'];

    // Optionally you may want $ans to be boolean:
    if($ans == 'Yes') {
        $ans = TRUE;
    } else {
        $ans = FALSE;
    }
}
```

then (if the table column is properly defined to store the boolean/integer/enum):

```
$q->execute(array($ans));
```

will store 1 (True) or 0 (False)

Comment: Even better, use NOT-empty() `if( !empty($_POST['choice']) )` instead of `isset()` because choice may be set but empty.